# $ \lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} r M(r)=0 $ implies $ \lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} \int \limits_{\gamma_{r}} f(z) d z=0 $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $ z_{0} \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ r_{0}>0 $. Let the function $ f $ be continuous outside the circle $ \partial B\left(z_{0}, r_{0}\right) $. We denote by $ M(r) $ the maximum of $ |f| $ on the set of all $ z $ with $ \left|z-z_{0}\right|=r>r_{0} $. Let
$$
\lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} r M(r)=0 .
$$

Show that then also
$$
\lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} \int \limits_{\gamma_{r}} f(z) d z=0
$$
where $ \gamma_{r} $ denotes an arc around $ z_{0} $ with radius $ r $.

**My Observation**:

$ \gamma(t)=z_{0}+r_0 e^{i t}, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi $

This parameterizes a counterclockwise circular line. $ \Gamma=\partial B\left(z_{0}, r_0\right) $.

$ \gamma'(t)=ir_0 e^{i t}, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi $

$
\lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} |\int \limits_{\gamma_{r}} f(z) d z|\leq \lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} max_{z \in \Gamma}|f(z)|\cdot l({\gamma_{r}})
$ with Estimation lemma

Comment: $| \int \limits_{\gamma_{r}} f(z) d z| \leq (2\pi r)M(r)$.